# Duplicating an MPI derived type vs. setting one type equal to another

Tags: fortran, mpi, derived-types

Let's say I have an MPI derived type, `type_a` in a Fortran code.  I would like a second copy of it, `type_b`.  Is there a practical difference between

```
call mpi_type_dup(type_a, type_b, err)
```

and

`type_b = type_a`  ?

I don't want to change any of the "associated key values" that the MPI standard mentions.

Is one of these to be preferred to the other?  Also, if `type_a` is already committed, do I still have to commit `type_b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran, a derived datatype is an integer (that is abstracted if you use `mpi_f08` bindings.

If you `type_b=type_a`, then you do not have to commit `type_b` before using it for communications, but if you later `call mpi_type_free(type_a)`, then`type_b` cannot be used any more.

If you duplicate `type_a`, then you have to commit `type_b` before using it for communications, both types are independent and both must be free'd when they are no more needed.

Regarding the "associated key values"

> MPI_Type_dup is a type constructor that duplicates the existing type with associated key values. For each key value, the respective copy callback function determines the attribute value associated with this key in the new communicator. One particular action that a copy callback may take is to delete the attribute from the new data type.

So as long as all the copy callback functions do preserve the attributes, this subroutine can be used.

If you know that `type_a` won't be free'd when `type_b` is used, then `type_b=type_a` is much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Where did you get the quote from? "in the new communicator" looks wrong, I'm assuming it should read "in the new data type"

Comment: Open MPI man page (!) Do you want to issue a PR? If not, I’ll be happy to do it and credit you for spotting it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet  Very clear and helpful.  Thanks!